# Почему в том случае пробелы есть, а в данном нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Получается пишу свою небольшую игру.
И вот столкнулся с такой небольшой проблемой.
[image: Скриншот проблемы]

В первом случае, при загрузке, этот самый ползунок заполняется без пробелов, а во всех других почему-то с этими самыми пробелами.
Проблема не особо большая, но раздражает немного.

Вот код функции при помощи который я генерирую данный индикатор:

```py
import math
def loadStringGenerator(filling, a):
    notfilledindicator = "⬜"
    filledindicator = "⬛"
    o = ""
    for i in range(math.ceil(a*filling)):
        o += notfilledindicator
    for i in range(math.floor((1-filling)*a)):
        o += filledindicator
    s = "[{}]".format(o)
    return s
```

А вот те самые строки которые я вывожу:

```py
#Первая:
print("\rLoading locals:{}{}%".format(utils.loadStringGenerator(localScanned / localsCount, 10),round((localScanned / localsCount) * 100, 1)), end="")

#Вторая:
print(localization.engine.loadingmods.format(utils.loadStringGenerator(currModNum / modCount, 10), round((currModNum / modCount) * 100, 1)), end="")

#Третья:
print(localization.engine.initializingmods.format(utils.loadStringGenerator(currModNum / modCount, 10), round((currModNum / modCount) * 100, 1)), end="")
```

Буду благодарен любой помощи, так как вообще не понимаю как это исправить.

Comment: у вас #Первая начинается с '\r' (перемещение курсора в начало строки), во #Вторая и #Третья - нет

Comment: А, кстати да, спасибо, я этого не заметил.

Comment: Скорее всего то, как эти символы отображаются, зависит от используемого шрифта.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, я смог сам разобраться, сменив символы которые выводятся в консоль.
Но так-же спасибо [Jack_oS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/420098/jack-os) за ответ

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1282877/edit)